# Plotting multiple plots, but with offset ranges in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot a function of e and nu, where e is the eccentricity and nu the true anomaly. I am only looking at elliptical orbits so `0<e<1`. However, when I try to plot them against each other, I have a shape error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10) (5000)

I know this is because I only want 10 spaces for the eccentricity, but is there a way around this?

```
import numpy as np

e = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)

vvals = [[] for i in range(len(e))]
nu = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 5000)


for i in e:
    for j in nu:
        i = float(i)
        j = float(j)
        v = np.sqrt(e ** 2 + 2 * e * np.cos(nu) + 1)
        i = int(i)
        vvals[i].append(v)


for i in e:
    pylab.plot(nu, vvals[i])


pylab.show()
```

Comment: Your `for` loops are really wonky, to the point where I am not strictly sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: at any rate the error is coming from the line `v = np.sqrt(e ** 2 + 2 * e * np.cos(nu) + 1)` and has nothing to do with `matplotlib` and `numpy` in behaving correctly.

Comment: @tcaswell I want to make a plot for e = .1, .2, ... 1 and overlay them all on top of each other.

Comment: @dustin: `e` has shape (10) and `nu` has shape (5000)., so numpy can't figure out what you want to happen that gets fed to the `sqrt`.  Neither can I.  What calculation are you trying to do in this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
import numpy as np

e = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
vvals = []
nu = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 5000)
for i in e:
    v = np.sqrt(i ** 2 + 2 * i * np.cos(nu) + 1)
    vvals.append(v)

for v in vvals:
    pylab.plot(nu, v)

pylab.show()
```

`numpy` broadcasting is your friend ;)

If you want to get really fancy:

```
import numpy as np

e = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1).reshape(-1, 1)
nu = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 5000).reshape(1, -1)
vvals = np.sqrt((e ** 2) * np.ones(nu.shape) + 2 * e * np.cos(nu) + 1)

for v, _e in zip(vvals, e.ravel()):
    pylab.plot(nu.ravel(), v, label=str(_e))

pylab.legend()    

pylab.show()
```

Comment: the plot pops for a millisecond and then immediately closes.  How can I stop this?

Comment: I am using emacs through the shebang line and I have in my bashrc an alias for ipython --pylab=qt

Comment: it sounds like your python session is exiting as soon as the script exits.  (I use emacs + py-shell to keep an interactive shell around).  You should ask another question about how to get your system set up correctly, as that is out of the scope of your original question.

Comment: whenever I ask setup questions here, I get downvoted and closed so that doesn't really work out.

Comment: what is reshape doing and what is `np.ones(nu.shape)`?

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation [`ones`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html), [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#numpy.ndarray.reshape) and playing around in an interactive shell.